# How to delete the lines that starts with a specific word and end with a specific word

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk, sql

Eg:

```
CREATE TABLE COMM.ACL_ENTRY (
        ACL_OID CHAR(18) FOR BIT DATA NOT NULL ,
        USER_DESC_TYPE FOR COLUMN USER_00001 BIGINT NOT NULL ,
        USER_DESC_OID FOR COLUMN USER_00002 VARGRAPHIC(220) CCSID 13488 NOT NULL ,
        ACTIONS BIGINT NOT NULL ,
        CONSTRAINT COMM.PK5111 PRIMARY KEY( ACL_OID , USER_DESC_OID ) )
        ;

ALTER TABLE COMMUN.ACL_ENTRY
        ADD CONSTRAINT COMM.FK5111A
        FOREIGN KEY( ACL_OID )
        REFERENCES COMM.ACL ( OID )
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
```

As you can see in the above example. I want to delete the lines that start with word `ALTER` till it ends with a specific pattern `;` and print the deleted lines in another file.

Comment: Format your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` for both the tasks. It supports so called "addresses", which could be regular expressions:

```
sed -n -e '/^ALTER/,/;$/p' > another.file # Prints them,
sed -i~ -e '/^ALTER/,/;$/d'               # Deletes them.
```